# What's the cable configuration of a ribbon cable when aiming for a balanced characteristic impedance?

Tags: characteristic-impedance, ribbon-cable

The ribbon cable in [reference 1](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/1/ts-0875-C-1155517.pdf) states a balanced characteristic impedance of 122 Ω. For which configuration of the wires is this value valid? From [reference 2,](http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/news/3_10.htm) it becomes evident that the characteristic impedance is influenced by the arrangement. Two configurations are discussed there:

```
G S+ S- G
G S+ G S- G
```

G is ground, S+ is signal+ and S- is signal-

To my understanding, the latter configuration should result in a balanced characteristic impedance of exactly two times the unbalanced impedance of 73 Ω, thus giving 146 Ω - but the balanced characteristic impedance is stated as 122 ohms. Therefore, I think the first configuration was chosen when the characteristic impedance of the ribbon cable was measured.

Reference 1: https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/1/ts-0875-C-1155517.pdf

Reference 2: http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/news/3_10.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data sheet says this: -

> Note: Unbalanced is measured between ground-signal-ground conductors.
> Balanced is measured between signal conductors within a pair

So, "unbalanced" is fairly unambiguous but, "balanced" appears to me as if they chose a pair and didn't ground any conductors either side. This is why the capacitance stated is 12 pF / foot in "balanced" and 20.8 pF / foot when "unbalanced".

It's also why the inductance per foot is lower in "unbalanced" (two ground conductors will reduce inductance) at 110 nH / foot whilst in "balanced" the inductance is greater i.e. 180 nH / foot.

The maths: -

- Unbalanced \$Z_0 = \sqrt{110/0.0208} = 72.7\space\Omega\$
- Balanced \$Z_0 = \sqrt{180/0.012} = 122.5\space\Omega\$